# Math.Round() not working when exporting to excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, razor

In my view which I am exporting to excel, I display the value of this variable

```
VeryGoodPercentage = subQst.Question.ReponseList.Where(
            r => r.ReponseValeur == 4 &&
            Model.SelectedGroupContactList.Select(c => c.ContaId).Contains(r.ContaId.Value)
            ).ToList().Count() * 100
            /
            denominator;
```

And I display this way

```
<td class=xl76 align=right width=69 style='width:52pt'>@Math.Round(VeryGoodPercentage)%</td>
```

When I display the view without exporting to excel, everything works just fine. But when I open the exported Excel file, I found the value of that variable not rounded.

For examlpe :

In the view : 36%

In the excel file : 0.36

I use this line to generate the file:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: You seem to be talking about some exported Excel file - could you please show the relevant code that you are using in order to generate this file?

Comment: I edited the post, I put that line in my view

Comment: 36% and 0.36 would be the same - just excel did not fomat this as a percentage; i don't see that this is a rounding problem.

Comment: Agreed with Jook. That's a problem with formatting in Excel, it has strictly nothing to do with the Math.Round function.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but is there a way to make Excel format it as a percentage without doing it from excel itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution here

[Format HTML table cell so that Excel formats as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text)

just add this css param to the  tag :

```
mso-number-format:Percent;
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated:

36% and 0.36 should be the same - just excel did not fomat this as a percentage or did indeed interpreted 36 as a percentage - which will result in 0.36 as a number.

I don't see that this is a rounding problem, it is formatting or input or both.

Depending on what values `@Math.Round(VeryGoodPercentage)` produce - 0.xx or XX.XX - with % sign or without, excel will interpret this differently.

Some examples:

=0.36 will result in a number of 0.36

=36 will result in a number of 36

no suprises so far, but now:

=0.36% will result to 0.0036

=36% will result to 0.36

BUT those were Formulars, now if you would just use F2 on an empty 'default' formatted cell and write into it:

36% -> you would format this as percentage, which would display this as 36%, but if you would format it as 'default', then it would be the number 0.36!

0.36% -> would behave like 36%

hope this clears more than it confuses ;) good luck to you!

*edit:* and to make this even more fuzzy, in my country `.` is the symbol for thounsands, so you would have to use `,` instead.

*edit:* with VBA you could setup your column or cell to use a specific numberformat like this:

```
Table1.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```