# Change the data type of a column before performing export to excel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am trying to export the gridview to excel in C#.But there are some columns that have data like 0005467. So when I try to export the Gridview to Excel, the data inside the column becomes 5467 since it is treating this column as number and not as string.Also sometimes when there are lot of 0s in the end, it treats that number as exponential.I don't want this column to change since those are the IDs.
Is there any way to change the datatype of a selected column in c# before exporting the whole gridview to excel?

Code where I am exporting the Gridview to Excel:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fname + ".xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

I have tried inserting

```
Response.Write("<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>");
```

in the above code but it did not work.

Please help!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text)

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you want to change the datatype of a column,
first you need to remember that you cannot change the datatype of a column in a tale if that table already have data.So what you can do is clone the table first and assign to another table(new table) . Then change the datatype of the new table and copy all data from first table to newly created table.

here is one demo, for same export and import excel i am using this.

```
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        //This is the initial table
        DataTable dtDetails = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtDetails);

        //This is the table for whom i need to change the datatype of columns
        DataTable dtCloned = dtDetails.Clone();
        dtCloned.Columns["myColumn1"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dtCloned.Columns["myColumn2"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

        //Copy all data from first table to this new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtDetails.Rows)
        {
            dtCloned.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
        }

        GridProjectDetails.DataSource = dtCloned;
        GridProjectDetails.DataBind();

       //Then you can export this Grid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to export to csv format instead of excel (.xls)

For this you need to change the content type, use below line at line 2.

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fname + ".csv")