# mso custom format for [hh]:mm in export to excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, datetime

I am working on MVC4 format. I have a column which has `HH:MM` format.When i export to excel everything works fine. i mean in excel it is still `HH:MM` format But when value of hours is greater than 24 then its showing as `HH:MM:SS`

```
eg : 04:00 is showing as 04:00 but 31:42 is showing as 31:42:00.
```

can i use some style or something like that which will affect only that column not any other

How can i fix this problem ?

I have gone through 
[Format HTML table cell so that Excel formats as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text)
and 
http://cosicimiento.blogspot.in/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html

but how can i format hh:mm to [hh]:mm so that if hours are greater than 24 it still remain in [hh]:mm format

Answer (score 0):

Just write the given code below.
Its working fine.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<style> TD { mso-number-format:\'@'; } </style>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Manas answer it's almost correct, just the backslash is in wrong position. Correct line code is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<style> TD { mso-number-format:'\@'; }
```