# How to prevent exponential value like e+15 in excel sheet while converting html table into excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am generating the excel sheet but i am getting value exponential value in excel. please help how to format it as text or as original view like  2200202029393020 instead of 22002E+15

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = " ";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Employee_Detail.xls;");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" border=\"0\">");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr><td colspan=3 ><b><font size=6> Employee_Details</font></b></td></tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</table>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" border=\"1\">");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td><b><font size=4> Name </font></b></td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td><b><font size=4>Employee Id</font></b></td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td><b><font size=4>Department</font></b></td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Ram</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393020</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Accounts</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Jordan</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393021</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Sales</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");


    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Shyam</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393022</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Production</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");


    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Donald</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393023</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>HR</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</table>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: It is just excel formatting. If you want it to be a string, prefix it with a `'`

Comment: But single quote is still visible in excel doc after prefixing with '

Answer (score 1):

may be it's late, but this helps someone i think. because i spent too much time to find this solution .

You can add style to your "td" like that

```
"<td style='mso-number-format:\"\\@\";'>YOUR VALUE</td>"
```

or
you can add zero width space character after your "td" like that

```
"<td>&#8203;YOUR VALUE</td>"
```

[Format HTML table cell so that Excel formats as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text)

best regards.