# export html table to Excel numbers became dates

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I want to export a html table to Excel.

Table:

```
<div id="table">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody id="tabbodyExp">
        <tr>
            <th>2.5</th>
            <th>2.6</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#table').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But excel is turning all numbers that are written like that "2.5" to Dates. Is there a way to stop that or do I have to write all number like that "2,5".

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on scunliffe's post here: [Format HTML table cell so that Excel formats as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text/4620023#4620023) As per that post, you can apply this special CSS property to the table cell and Excel will start treating the value as a string instead of formatting it as number (hopefully this works the same for your Dates):

```
mso-number-format:"\@"; /*force text*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but i will add my answer as it can help to other users that try to use numbers in excel.

In my case `mso-number-format:"\@";` does not work so i use `vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:0.0;`

Example:

```
<th style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:0.0;">2.5</th>
```

or

```
<th style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:0.0;">2,5</th>
```