# How to format excel cell 'text' when opening an HTML content

Tags: java, excel, xsl-fo, bi-publisher

We use Oracle BI Publisher to create the data that can be written to files(pdf,excel,html...).

I've checked the created data, it is an html page(contain the format and business data,created by oracle bi publisher using XSL-FO). And we use java to just write the data to a xls file(no POI is used).

When the data contain '=cmd|'/C calc'!A0', this value in excel cell(General cell type) will try to call 'cmd' to open windows Calculator(we don't want this happen). If the excel cell format is 'text', the value will be ok.

So how can I make write such html data into excel with all excel cell format is 'text'? or any other way to avoid '=cmd|'/C calc'!A0' issue in excel?

```html
<html>
<!-- Generated by Oracle BI Publisher 11.1.1.6.0 -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css" id="internalStyle">
.c0 {height: 26.25pt;}
.c1 {word-wrap:break-word;width:14.999%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c2 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;}
.c3 {word-wrap:break-word;width:70.0%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c4 {line-height: 18.35pt;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 2.834pt;margin-left: 0.176pt;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c5 {font-family: 'Arial';font-size: 15.874pt;color: #333333;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c6 {text-align: right;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 2.834pt;margin-left: 0.666pt;}
.c7 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;table-layout:fixed;margin-left: 0.511pt;margin-right: auto;width: 667.842pt;border-collapse: collapse;}
.c8 {height: 15.285pt;}
.c9 {word-wrap:break-word;width:100.0%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c10 {line-height: 12.451pt;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 2.834pt;}
.c11 {font-family: 'Arial';font-size: 10.771pt;color: #333333;}
.c12 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;table-layout:fixed;margin-left: 0.511pt;margin-right: auto;width: 640.629pt;border-collapse: collapse;}
.c13 {height: 12.009pt;}
.c14 {word-wrap:break-word;width:15.293%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c15 {line-height: 9.175pt;margin-top: 2.834pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;}
.c16 {font-family: 'Arial';font-size: 7.937pt;color: #333333;}
.c17 {word-wrap:break-word;width:71.193%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c18 {line-height: 9.175pt;margin-top: 2.834pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 0.385pt;}
.c19 {word-wrap:break-word;width:13.512%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c20 {text-align: right;margin-top: 2.834pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 0.195pt;}
.c21 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;table-layout:fixed;margin-left: 0.511pt;margin-right: auto;width: 741.372pt;border-collapse: collapse;}
.c22 {height: 13.675pt;}
.c23 {word-wrap:break-word;border-width: 0.25pt;border-color: #d6d6d6;border-style: solid;width:14.285%;background-color: #efefef;}
.c24 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 1.542pt;margin-right: 1.195pt;}
.c25 {word-wrap:break-word;border-top-width: 0.25pt;border-top-color: #d6d6d6;border-top-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 0.25pt;border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;border-bottom-style: solid;border-right-width: 0.25pt;border-right-color: #d6d6d6;border-right-style: solid;width:42.857%;background-color: #efefef;}
.c26 {line-height: 9.175pt;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 1.763pt;margin-right: 1.156pt;}
.c27 {line-height: 9.175pt;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 1.802pt;margin-right: 1.117pt;}
.c28 {word-wrap:break-word;border-width: 0.25pt;border-color: #d6d6d6;border-style: solid;width:100.0%;background-color: #efefef;}
.c29 {line-height: 9.175pt;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 1.542pt;margin-right: 1.117pt;}
.c30 {height: 16.826pt;}
.c31 {word-wrap:break-word;border-bottom-width: 0.25pt;border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;border-bottom-style: solid;border-left-width: 0.25pt;border-left-color: #d6d6d6;border-left-style: solid;border-right-width: 0.25pt;border-right-color: #d6d6d6;border-right-style: solid;width:57.142%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c32 {line-height: 12.451pt;margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 1.542pt;margin-right: 1.156pt;}
.c33 {word-wrap:break-word;border-bottom-width: 0.25pt;border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;border-bottom-style: solid;border-right-width: 0.25pt;border-right-color: #d6d6d6;border-right-style: solid;width:42.857%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c34 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;margin-left: 1.802pt;margin-right: 1.117pt;}
.c35 {height: 13.55pt;}
.c36 {word-wrap:break-word;border-bottom-width: 0.25pt;border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;border-bottom-style: solid;border-left-width: 0.25pt;border-left-color: #d6d6d6;border-left-style: solid;border-right-width: 0.25pt;border-right-color: #d6d6d6;border-right-style: solid;width:14.285%;background-color: #ffffff;}
.c37 {margin-top: 0.0pt;margin-bottom: 0.0pt;table-layout:fixed;margin-left: 0.511pt;margin-right: auto;width: 198.424pt;border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="c7">
<col width="14.999%"/>
<col width="70.0%"/>
<col width="14.999%"/>
<tr class="c0">
<td valign="top" class="c1"><p class="c2"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c3"><p class="c4"><span class="c5">Item</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c1"><p class="c6"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="c12">
<col width="100.0%"/>
<col width="0.0%"/>
<tr class="c8">
<td valign="top" colspan="2" class="c9"><p class="c10"><span class="c11">TEST NO BUSINESS DATA</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="c37">
<col width="14.285%"/>
<col width="42.857%"/>
<col width="42.857%"/>
<tr class="c22">
<td valign="middle" class="c23"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c25"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"><b>test  </b></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c25"><p class="c27"><span class="c16"><b>test  </b></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c22">
<td valign="middle" class="c23"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c25"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"><b></b></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c25"><p class="c27"><span class="c16"><b></b></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c22">
<td valign="middle" colspan="3" class="c28"><p class="c29"><span class="c16"><b></b></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c30">
<td valign="middle" colspan="2" class="c31"><p class="c32"><span class="c11">Title&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c27"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c27"><span class="c16">=cmd|'/C&nbsp;calc'!A0</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c27"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c35">
<td valign="middle" class="c36"><p class="c24"><br/></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c26"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="middle" class="c33"><p class="c34"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="c21">
<col width="15.293%"/>
<col width="71.193%"/>
<col width="13.512%"/>
<tr class="c13">
<td valign="top" class="c14"><p class="c15"><span class="c16"><b></b></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c17"><p class="c18"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c19"><p class="c20"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c13">
<td valign="top" class="c14"><p class="c15"><span class="c16"><b></b></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c17"><p class="c18"><span class="c16"></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c19"><p class="c20"><br/></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for changing in html page. Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620023/7472144).
Make `<td>` with CSS style `mso-number-format:"\@";`