# Export table to excel and columns to be in text format

Tags: javascript, excel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table, filesaver.js

I am using `bootstrap-table` to show tables in my page and I use `TableExport.js` , `FileSaver.js` and `.xlsx.core.min.js` libraries in order to save the table in `.xlslx` format.

The problem is that the below column in excel is shown in general format, causing the values to be displayed like `1,00582E+11`, while the right value is `100582012421`.

I tried `data-tableexport-msonumberformat="\@"` to force export process to treat this column as a text, but the result didn't change. I also read this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text) and I create a `CSS` class

`.text{
  mso-number-format:"\@";/*force text*/
}`

but neither this solution worked for me..

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover" 
       ...
       data-url="myfile.json" 
       ...                
       >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
            <th data-field="productId" data-tableexport-msonumberformat="\@">Product</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Use into td the class **tableexport-string**

```
<td class="tableexport-string">{{$Rep->deviceName}}</td>
```