# ActiveWorkbook.Queries does not compile

Tags: excel, vba

There is [big bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151491/convert-html-table-to-excel-using-vba) which has prompted some very interesting answers.  One answer involves Power Query (I think) but the code does not compile for me.  I have installed [Power Query](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) but the code still does not compile.

I am using Excel 2013 Home and Student Edition 32-bit running on Windows 10 64 bit Pro.

Is this in a "higher"/more expensive edition of Excel?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Debug.Print TypeName(ActiveWorkbook.queries)

End Sub
```

above code throws error box saying

> Method or data member not found

Is this Office 365 only? [Queries.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/queries-add-method-excel)

Answer (score 1):

> An object that represents a query that was created by Power Query.
>   **Introduced in Office 2016**.

from [WorkbookQuery Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbookquery-object-excel)