# How can I see "Large Numbers" (+14 digits) when I open a htm file on Excel?

Tags: html, excel

I have a htm file which I usually open in Excel to perform some analytics. In the original file, I have this number: `64971368131291229`. However, when I open the file in Excel the number changes to `64971368131291220`.

I think this is happening because Excel automatically changes to 0's all the numbers after the 14th digit.

I have read that in the case of using large numbers in VBA, this problem can be solved by turning the integer number into a string. However, in this case, the number is changed to 0's since Excel opens the file with no opportunity to turning into the original one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have control over this HTM file? you can format the data as text before opening it in excel. I think this example may work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text Edit: there are many answers that work not just the top one