# Export Excel : Avoid stripping the leading zeros

Tags: c#-4.0

I am Export a data to Excel Sheet in C#.Net. There i am having column which has the data like "00123450098". The data is exported without the first zero's. I want to show the data as it is.

Here is my export excel code.

```
 string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
        "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    ...................
    ...................
     table.RenderControl(htw);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(style);
            //render the htmlwriter into the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Excel file, Numbers cell always strips the leading zeros, you can set numbers with leading zeros by following a single quote. i.e.

> 00123450098  to '00123450098

but then, the format for that cell will changes to text.
If your generated excel file, have any formula, which is include that cell reference as number then it will not work as expected.

Comment: this i checked..but the single quotes are also exported to excel...how to avoid that..

Comment: Yes, this single quote will also export to display leading zeros, and if you don't want to place single quote, then you should provide a number format to the cell in your code.

Answer (score 25):

While exporting  to excel, adding `\t` before the value being inserted will solve the problem.
Eg:

```
string test = "000456";
string insertValueAs = "\t" + test;
```

The string test would then be considered as a string value and not an integer value. Thus, it would retain the leading zeros.

I have faced the same issue, and above solution worked for me. Hope this post helps!

Comment: Hey @viacheslav,  appending "\t" to data is not working for me, it is still removing starting zero.

Comment: Hey, this works for me. The zeroes remain in cell. But it adds a tab space before the start of the string. Is there any alternative I could use ?

Answer (score 9):

If exporting to CSV / TSV, put this into each cell containing a textual "number" with leading 0s or (especially) 16+ digits:

="0012345"

..where 0012345 is the number you want to export to that cell.

I wish I could remember where I saw that.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well. The solution I came up with was to sneak the leading zeros in using excel's built in char() function. In excel, char() returns the value of the ASCII character code that is passed to it, so char(048) returns 0.
Before exporting to excel, prepend your variable like so...

```
varName = "=CHAR(048)&" + varName;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer for this using a combination of [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105038/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-issue-with-decimal-formatting-for-numbers-greater-th) and a [blog](http://niallodoherty.com/post.cfm/basic-html-to-excel-formatting).
There are excel formatting styles that can be applied to the gridview on rowdatabound. I used those and now my export does not strip the leading zeros.

Below is an example of my code.

```
ExpenseResultsGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(ExpenseResultsGrid_RowDataBound);

        protected void AllQuartersGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {//add this style to prevent truncating leading zeros in fund code during export to excel
                e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("mso-number-format", "\\@");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

While exporting, just add an empty string like "" before the value that is inserted:

```
string x = "000123";
myWorksheet.Cells[1,1] = "" + x;
```

Comment: Didnt work. Outputed the same integer without leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `&nbsp;` in front. For example:

```
StrBody.Append("<td><table><tr><td><b>&nbsp;" & structDb.dstResult.Tables(1).Rows(k).Item("BeneficiaryAccountNo") & "</td></tr></table></td>")
```